# Is it possible to import a Word document into the ActiveWindow

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I'm currently developing a VSTO Word Addin for Office 2013. In this Addin it sould be possible to open a document from the filesystem.
I use this codesnippet to do this:

```
     Word.Document doc = this.Application.Documents.Open(FilePath, ReadOnly: false, AddToRecentFiles: false);
     doc.ActiveWindow.View.Type = Word.WdViewType.wdPrintView;
```

Now my question, how it is possible to open the Document in the current Window?
When i use the codesnippet above Word closes the activeWindow and open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to know How the existing file (Active document) closed and the new document is opened.

If that is correct, Below code

```
Word.Document doc = this.Application.Documents.Open(FilePath, ReadOnly: false, AddToRecentFiles: false);
```

Declared "doc" object is MSword application itself. since It closed the existing one and opened the new document.

Comment: HI, thank you for the quick response. But thats not my Problem. I know how to open a new Document. But when i do this Word closes the active Window and open a new one. The result is that it flickers and I want to prevent this.